# How to enforce c# 10's static interface properties to be implemented?

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

c# 10's static interface properties obviously get automatically implemented. How to enforce overriding it?

```cs
    public interface IModelLogicEventSubsciptions
    {
        static EventSubscriptionType EventSubscriptions { get; }
    }
```

```cs
    public interface AnyClass : IModelLogicEventSubsciptions
    {
        //static EventSubscriptionType EventSubscriptions { get; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is to mark the interface member as abstract

```cs
public interface IModelLogicEventSubsciptions
{
    static abstract EventSubscriptionType EventSubscriptions { get; }
}
```